# Design a NMOS with low drain-source resistance

Tags: current, mosfet

I am designing a reference circuit, and currently in the step of outputting a large current(80mA) through a 180nm technology diode-connected NMOS. The problem is, as I have tested, the current curve result is best for my work if I have small *drain source resistance* in the NMOS. However, my NMOS is limited by its technology, thus the value of W is maximum 200u, and L is minimum 350n. I have tried this maximum value of W/L, and the result is still nowhere near optimum.

**My question**: is there any possible way to even lower the resistance, W and L modifications asides? I would hope to have as low as 50 or 10 ohm. Extra component is also welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Achieving a resistance lower than 10 ohms should be no problem at all.

First figure out what resistance a single transistor has considering the worst case conditions (process variation, temperature, voltage) that might occur. Then put as many of these transistors in parallel to lower the total resistance to the desired value.

Before doing that, check the available devices in your technology and try to single out the one that has the best properties for this application.